# Batch obfuscation with proguard

Tags: java, proguard

I need to obfuscate a list of jars files. What is the best method for doing this ?. This jars has inter dependencies. Do I need to write separate proguard conf file for each jar and to write a script to iterate through it ?. Or any better methods already available ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to achieve this by creating a gradle task

- Install latest gradle
- Create a directory and execute `gradle init` and select basic
- Create a text file where all the input jars specified to obfuscate
- Create the proguard.conf
- Update the build.gradle with the following task.

  ```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
      classpath 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.0.3'
      classpath 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-base:6.0.3'
    }
  }
  task proguard(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
   configuration 'proguard.conf'
   new File("${System.getProperty('user.dir')}/injars.txt").eachLine { file ->
        injars "${System.getProperty('user.dir')}/inputjars/${file}"
        outjars "${System.getProperty('user.dir')}/outputjars/${file}"
   }

   libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/lib/rt.jar"
   libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/lib/jce.jar"
   libraryjars "${System.getProperty('user.dir')}/dependencies/"    //All the dependant libraries    
  }
  ```